# Funcao load do Jquery nao funciona

Tags: jquery

Mesmo seguindo a documentacao oficial da Jquery, meu script nao funciona. Algo do dia para o outro. Nao sei se alterei algo sem querer.

Segue codigo abaixo

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>load demo</title>
  <style>
  body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Projects:</b>
<ol id="new-projects"></ol>

<script>
$( "#new-projects" ).load( "load.html #projects li" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

- Ja mudei o arquivo Jquery para o mais recente.
- Ja testei em navegadores diferentes
- Ja verifiquei topicos semelhantes (nao tao semelhantes assim)

Existe alguma restricao do AJAX para carregar paginas estaticas?
Nao sei o que esta acontecendo. Nao quero rodar uma pagina dinamicamente ao lado do servidor (php) pois estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo html5 para mobile. Sei que existem formas de rodar o php em um smartphone. Nao quero!

Comment: Nunca usei dessa forma mas... tenta por só $( "#new-projects" ).load( "load.html" ); e vê se funciona...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não funciona se você estiver abrindo o arquivo diretamente do disco.

O protocolo não suporta `Cross-Origin`, só conseguirá executar esse exemplo utilizando um servidor `http`

Resposta de referência: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10752078/5325043

Comment: Problema resolvido!
Causa: Desconhecimento sobre o AJAX. Por uma interpretação errada que tive da tecnica AJAX, associei ela apenas como client-side. O que nao e verdade. Foi so eu colocar na pasta do servidor Apache que funcionou.
Para quem tem o mesmo problema, saiba que essa funcao da Jquery nao funciona fora de um servidor.

Comment: Se a resposta lhe foi útil pode marca-la como aceita, dessa forma outras pessoas podem saber que o problema foi solucionado

Comment: Não só foi solucionado, como tive problema similar usando JQuery Mobile. 
Marquei como solucionada!

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido! Causa: Desconhecimento sobre o AJAX. Por uma interpretação errada que tive da tecnica AJAX, associei ela apenas como client-side. O que nao e verdade. Foi so eu colocar na pasta do servidor Apache que funcionou. Para quem tem o mesmo problema, saiba que essa funcao da Jquery nao funciona fora de um servidor.

Sobre o AJAX
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Sobre a funcao Load da Jquery
https://api.jquery.com/load/